# Dynamically nest the execution of functions using array_reduce() and an array of callbacks

Tags: php, arrays, callback, nested-function

I am new to PHP and am currently messing around with `array_reduce`, when I see this happen:

```php
php > echo array_reduce(array("(function($x){return $x;})"), function($p, $q) {return ($q)($p);}, "init");

Warning: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function (function(, ){return ;})() in php shell code:1
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: {closure}('init', '(function(, ){r...')
#1 php shell code(1): array_reduce(Array, Object(Closure), 'init')
#2 {main}
  thrown in php shell code on line 1

php > echo (function($x){return $x;})("init");
init
```

Essentially, there are three parts to `array_reduce()` - the array, the reduce function and an initial value. Here my reduce function takes two strings `func($x, $y)` and calls `$y` with the argument `$x` - `return ($y)($x);`. So I expect that calling `array_reduce(array(a1, a2, a3), ..., "init")`, it will return `a1(a2(a3("init")))` as repeated function calls.

Hence, I also pass in an anonymous function `(function($x){return $x;})` as `a1`, hoping it will call correctly and return `"init"` as the final result. Indeed when running it on its own (see the second php command), it returns `"init"` correctly. However when passing into `array_reduce()`, it does not work. Can someone help explain why, preferably in simple terms? And is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: crazy idea remove the quotes, quotes creates strings!

Comment: @Breezer here's the thing, they have to be there... the strings are read from somewhere else (similar to `readline`)and passed into `array_reduce(<my_string>, function($p, $q) {return ($q)($p);}, "init")` as a string. Hope there's some other way haha.

Comment: Well if it has to be a string, which I would greatly discourage you could always use `eval()`

Comment: ... and don't forget to escape your dollar signs in double quoted string

Comment: @Breezer @user1597430 Thank you for your reply. I have gotten to `(function($x){return $x;})(123)` will return 123 as expected, so I should turn the first parentheses into eval and escape the string, right? I imagine it's something like `eval("(function(\$x){return \$x;})")(123)`, but it throws a syntax error. Do you mind helping out? Thanks!!

Comment: Actually, just an update: `echo (eval("function(\$x){return \$x;};"))(123);` throws an error "Function name must be a string in php shell code:" - but I am trying to make an anonymous function, why would it have a function name?

Comment: you're going about it wrong, eval doesnt return anything, it just runs your code, I would've done something like this
`$var = eval("return (function(\$x){return \$x;});");
echo array_reduce(array($var), function($p, $q) {return ($q)($p);}, "init");`

Comment: Can you provide `a1()`, `a2()`, and `a3()` and your desired result so that we have a [mcve]?

Comment: @mickmackusa Unfortunately it's been a long time since I touched that problem, plus as mentioned in the post I was simply messing around with PHP with no particular goal, so I don't have the examples I had in mind, sorry :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be aware of the issues when using [`eval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), as noted on the PHP documentation:

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

I would suggest that you only use `eval` for constant strings that you already have. Definitely do not allow arbitrary strings that the user has provided into `eval` without significant sanitisation; I would suggest that even then it is likely to be too much of a security hole.

If you still wish to proceed with using `eval`, you could do something like:

```
<?php

$definitions = [
  '(function($x){return "a1({$x})";})',
  '(function($x){return "a2({$x})";})',
  '(function($x){return "a3({$x})";})',
];

$functions = array_map(fn($f) => eval("return {$f};"), array_reverse($definitions));

$output = array_reduce($functions, fn($p, $q) => $q($p), 'init');

echo "{$output}\n";
```

This uses:

- [`array_reverse`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) to create a reversed definitions array, as the functions would be applied from the inside out (ie, without it, the output would be `a3(a2(a1(init)))`)
- [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and `eval` to map the array of definitions (as strings) to anonymous functions
- [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) throughout as a bit of syntactic sugar to make it a bit neater